# namespace system has no member Drawing in c++

Tags: image, visual-c++, graphics, msdn

when I am trying to use System::Drawing it giving error "namespace system has no member Drawing".

Code:
using namespace System::Drawing;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you didn't add the `System::Drawing` reference

Goto `Project -> References -> Common Properties -> Framework and References`

Click `Add New References...` button

Under `Assemblies -> Frameworks` check `System.Drawing` and click ok.

**Update - 2017.8.22**

You can click `Project -> Add Reference...` in Visual Studio 2015.