# Namespace "System::IO" has no member "ports"

Tags: c++, port, visual-studio-2019, system

I'm working with Visual Studio 2019. I'm modifying an old code I found and it has this error:

> namespace "System::IO" has no member "Ports"

Goal is to create a plugin, extension .dll, and I already have a C++/CLI file. The code:

```
#include "DisplaySteering.hpp"          
#include <math.h>               
#include <stdio.h>              
#include <stdlib.h>
#using <system.dll> 
#include <string.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::IO::Ports;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;
```

I understand I have to activate the class, but how? I saw this post [namespace system has no member Drawing in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34527537/namespace-system-has-no-member-drawing-in-c)
but couldn't find the option for ports (link is visual studio 2017, I have 2019)

This may be a very beginner question, but couldn't find an answer it works. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a .net compiler complain about something that it does not know about, but you are sure it exists, look at the documentation to check in which assembly it is implemented.

Unfortunately this only works for classes (because namespaces can spread across multiple assemblies), so pick the class you want to use and open its documentation, for example:

https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport

Make sure you select the version of .net you are using in the dropdown on the left.

Then, right at the top, it tells you that for .net Framework 5, the class is implemented in `System.IO.Ports.dll`, which is probably the assembly that you need to reference for your program to compile.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I already read this document before asking, but I didn't know if I was calling it correctly, because I already tried `include <System.IO.Ports.dll>` and gives the error `origin file couldn't be opened`. I also tried `using System.IO.Ports;`, but this one gave the error `namespace "System::IO" has no member "Ports"`. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `#include <System.IO.Ports.dll>`

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried this myself and I think that you are supposed to add the reference to System.IO.Ports.dll via nuget. However, nuget does not seem to work with C++/CLI projects. I got around that by creating a C# project, adding the nuget reference there, picked the DLL and added a reference to the C++/CLI project... and then it did compile.

Comment: That looks really complicatly for my level... Could I speak to you privately, please?